# Tycho for Product and feature

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, e4, tycho

I'm creating a maven project from my Eclipse E4 application (product and feature project). After searching some tutorials I got three maven file that imports all the dependencies. One maven file for the feature project, one for the product project and one parent.

My target definition looks like:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="0.0"?>

<target name="eclipse neon">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeMode="planner" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.resources" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.pshelf" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.e4" version="0.0.0"/>

            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="ca.odell.glazedlists" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ui.forms" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository" version="0.0.0"/>

            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.databinding" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86_64" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86_64" version="0.0.0"/>

            <unit id="javax.annotation" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="javax.inject" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="javax.wsdl" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="javax.xml" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.batik.css" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.batik.util" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.batik.util.gui" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.codec" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.jxpath" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.logging" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.commands" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.contenttype" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.databinding" version="0.0.0"/>

            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.swt" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.w3c.css.sac" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.databinding" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.property" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.swt" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.registry" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.app" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.services" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jface" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jface.databinding" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.osgi.services" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.jobs" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.expressions" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.osgi" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.common" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.registry" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.swt" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.expressions" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.batik.util" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.property" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.osgi" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.jobs" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.contenttype" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.app" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.w3c.dom.smil" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.osgi" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.services" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.commands" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.emf.xpath" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.registry" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.osgi" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.jobs" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.swt" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jface" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.apache.batik.css" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.osgi" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.osgi.services" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.services" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.swt" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jface" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.swt" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.commands" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.swt" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.apache.batik.util.gui" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.jobs" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.resources" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.apache.commons.jxpath" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="javax.inject" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.swt" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jface" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.pshelf" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.core.services" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.e4" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="ca.odell.glazedlists" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.ui.forms" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.swt" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.w3c.css.sac" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jface" version="0.0.0"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.tukaani.xz" version="0.0.0" />
            <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" version="0.0.0" />

            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nattable/releases/1.4.0/repository/"/>
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/"/>
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nebula/snapshot/"/>
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nebula/incubation/snapshot/"/>
            <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/nattable/snapshots/latest/repository/"/>
        </location>
    </locations>
</target>
```

The feature pom looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.atlascopco</groupId>
  <artifactId>CR_IT_Client_Feature</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-feature</packaging>
  <name>CR IT Client Feature</name>

    <parent>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <groupId>com.atlascopco</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    </parent>

</project>
```

The product pom looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.atlascopco</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipse-repository</artifactId>
  <version>0.13.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>
  <name>CR IT Client Feature</name> 

    <parent>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <groupId>com.atlascopco</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <win32>zip</win32>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>materialize-products</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>materialize-products</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>archive-products</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>archive-products</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And finally the parent pom:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.atlascopco</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>RCP Parent</name>

    <properties>
        <tycho-version>1.0.0</tycho-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
    <module>CR-IT client</module>
        <module>CR_IT Client Feature</module>

        <module>neon</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.swtchart</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.swtchart</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.gettext-commons/gettext-commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.gettext-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>gettext-commons</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
          <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${tycho-version}</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>

                    <target>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>com.atlascopco</groupId>
                            <artifactId>neon</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        </artifact>
                    </target>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When building the parent project I got an error on the eclipse-repository maven file. Maven compiles the RCP Parent and the CR IT Client Feature without any problem. But when compiling the eclipse-repository project I got following error:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: CR-IT_client_ID 0.13.1.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: CR-IT_client_ID 0.13.1.qualifier requires 'CR_IT_
Client_Feature.feature.group [1.0.0,1.0.1)' but it could not be found
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-repository-plugin:1.0.
    0:assemble-repository (default-assemble-repository) on project eclipse-repositor
    y: Execution default-assemble-repository of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-repo
    sitory-plugin:1.0.0:assemble-repository failed: Cannot resolve dependencies of M
    avenProject: com.atlascopco:eclipse-repository:0.13.1-SNAPSHOT @ [path to the projects]\framework\CR-IT client\pom.xml: See log for details -> [Help
     1]
```

Detailed error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-repository-plugin:1.0.0:assemble-repository (default-assemble-repository) on project eclipse-repository: Execution default-assemble-repository of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-repository-plugin:1.0.0:assemble-repository failed: Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: com.atlascopco:eclipse-repository:0.13.1-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\air27654\Documents\Source\framework\CR-IT client\pom.xml: See log for details -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-repository-plugin:1.0.0:assemble-repository (default-assemble-repository) on project eclipse-repository: Execution default-assemble-repository of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-repository-plugin:1.0.0:assemble-repository failed: Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: com.atlascopco:eclipse-repository:0.13.1-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\air27654\Documents\Source\framework\CR-IT client\pom.xml
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-assemble-repository of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-repository-plugin:1.0.0:assemble-repository failed: Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: com.atlascopco:eclipse-repository:0.13.1-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\air27654\Documents\Source\framework\CR-IT client\pom.xml
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.artifacts.DependencyResolutionException: Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: com.atlascopco:eclipse-repository:0.13.1-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\air27654\Documents\Source\framework\CR-IT client\pom.xml
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.doResolveDependencies(P2DependencyResolver.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.resolveDependencies(P2DependencyResolver.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.facade.RepositoryReferenceTool.addTargetPlatformRepository(RepositoryReferenceTool.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.facade.RepositoryReferenceTool.getVisibleRepositories(RepositoryReferenceTool.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.plugins.p2.repository.AssembleRepositoryMojo.getVisibleRepositories(AssembleRepositoryMojo.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.plugins.p2.repository.AssembleRepositoryMojo.execute(AssembleRepositoryMojo.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.ResolverException: See log for details
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.ProjectorResolutionStrategy.resolve(ProjectorResolutionStrategy.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.AbstractResolutionStrategy.resolve(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:195)
    ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my project setup from a featured based to a plugin based. After including all the requirements in the product file and removing all the feature links from the pom files it will compile and run afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use a parent POM that specifies the general plugins, dependencies and a modules section. The modules section points to the product and the feature projects.

Also I noticed that you mix p2 dependencies with Maven dependencies. In such a case you need to set pomDependencies=consider as explained here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/How_Tos/Dependency_on_pom-first_artifacts

I also wrote a blog post about that some years ago: http://blog.vogella.com/2013/01/03/tycho-advanced/

Comment: Followed a tycho example and now I got one error. I changed my question for that.

Comment: I already said in my answer that you need to set pomDependencies=consider if you mix p2 dependencies with Maven dependencies. Add the following in the configuration section of the target-platform-configuration plugin <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies> - but that will also only work at runtime if all your dependencies are available as OSGi bundles.

Comment: Changed my pom file and added <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>. Now I got an error that my feature is not found for my product project.

Comment: Have you tried to change the order of your modules? Actually it should resolve them in the correct order, but maybe there is an issue.

Comment: Change the modules in all the different possible order. Everytime I got the error. One thing I found strange in the error, the repository project does need a requirement CR_IT_Client_Feature.feature.group [1.0.0,1.0.1) but there is only a feature named CR_IT_Client_Feature and not CR_IT_Client_Feature.feature.group. Where can it be go wrong here?

Comment: That is the name of the p2 IU. Enable the debug output to get more detailed information

Comment: Added detailed errors to original question. Is it possible to disable the p2 generation. I only need the binary files of the compiled project. I do not use P2 update repository to update my application.

Comment: Well you use Tycho, and Tycho uses the p2 resolver to resolve the dependencies. Do you call mvn clean verify or what do you execute for building?

Comment: I do a normal "mvn clean install"

Comment: and you execute it on the parent POM? just for clarification

Comment: Yes I'm executing it on the parent POM

Comment: Then I don't have any further idea. Only the question why you are mixing target platform specification approaches. On the one side you specify repositories and on the other hand it seems you have a target definition. Not sure if that causes some strange effects. https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform

Comment: Because I use special Eclipse plugins like Nattable and swtchart in my applicatino

Comment: When I remove the neon repository I got another issue. Product has a missing requirement 'org.eclipse.core.filesystem'

Comment: I don't know your target definition. But NatTable is available as a p2 repository and can therefore be part of a target definition. SWTChart is available via Orbit http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/ and can therefore by also part of a target definition. In the end all the repositories you added in the repositories section can be part of the target definition. So again, I don't understand your setup with regards to the target definition.

Comment: Can you please give me an example what I'm doing wrong. I don't think I understood you correctly?

Comment: I don't know your setup and if you are actually using a target definition. If you do, then why do you specify repositories. If you don't, then why do you specify a target? You can have a look at the NatTable repository where the E4 examples application is build with pomless Tycho based on a target definition: https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable